# django - inlineformset - crispy - how to display non_field_errors

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms, inline-formset

I have the following CreateView

```
class CreatePerson(CreateView):
    model=Person
    form_class=PersonForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(CreatePerson, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['address_formset'] = AddressInlineFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context['address_formset'] = AddressInlineFormSet()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formset = context['address_formset']
        if formset.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            formset.instance = self.object
            formset.save()
            return super().form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

and the following form

```
{% load static crispy_forms_tags %}
...
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy form %}

    {{ address_formset.management_form }}

    {% for formset in address_formset %}
        {% crispy formset %}
    {% endfor %}
    ...
```

**How do I display the duplicate key error (occurred in the formset model) in the form?**

I have tried this way.

```
form_errors = formset.errors
return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form,form_errors=form_errors))
```

and

```
{{ form_errors }}
```

which gives the following display in the form.

```
[{}, {'__all__': ['Please correct the duplicate values below.']}]
```

How do I render it in crispy way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that I need was...

```
{% csrf_token %}

{% crispy form  %}

{% crispy address_formset address_formset.form.helper %}
```